# No Interface Expected RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener

Tags: android

Trying to Implement `RecyclerView`  ItemClickListener  using Android Studio  but getting error

"**No Interface Expected here** "

when I try to make `RecyclerToushListener` which extends `RecyclerView.onItemTouchListener` like this i am getting this error

```
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

    /**
 * Created by Admin on 9/18/2016.
 */
public class RecyclerTouchListener extends RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

    }

  public interface  clicklistener{
        public void onItemclick();
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't use `extends` with an interface, you use `implements`.

```
public class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener
```